# nar-maven-plugin eclipse API Incompatibility

Tags: c++, eclipse, maven, plugins

I'm using eclipse to compile/run my projects. I tried to use maven on c++ projects with nar-maven-plugin to build them. It works well as i launch maven goals in command line.

But when i import my maven project in eclipse, i have the following errors :

> Execution default-nar-compile of goal
>   com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-compile failed: An API
>   incompatibility was encountered while executing
>   com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-compile:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner.setupMatchPatterns()V
>   ----------------------------------------------------- realm =    plugin>com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3 strategy =
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
>   ...

Moreover, eclipse seems to manage my project as a Java project instead of a C project.

Note : i'm using

```
Eclipse 4.3.1
M2E 1.4.0
CDT 8.3.0
```

My pom.xml

```
<project
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworld-cplusplus-sample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>nar</packaging>
  <name>Helloworld</name>
  <properties>
    <rootdir>${project.basedir}</rootdir>
    <nar.linker>gpp</nar.linker>
    <nar.arch>x86</nar.arch>
    <nar.os>Windows</nar.os>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
          only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[3.2.3,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>nar-test-unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
        <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <linker>
            <name>g++</name>
          </linker>        
          <libraries>
            <library>
              <type>executable</type>
            </library>
          </libraries>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
      <artifactId>helloworld-shared-library-sample</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>nar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

If someone is using nar-maven-plugin with eclipse can help me :). I would really like to use it on eclipse.

Thanks!